# rendering an array of strings and add between each element a new line - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'm trying to do is in the return of a render method, to add a newline between each element of an array (of strings).

I've tried two ways (one of them is commented):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
            <div className='Dog'>
                {this.props.name}
                <p>Age: {this.props.age}</p>
                {/* <text>About: {this.props.fact.map((f) => f+'\n')}</text> */}
                <p>{this.props.fact.join('\n')}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The result is not what I was looking for:

image #1 - result **without any of my attempts** (as if - just rendering {this.props.fact}:

[image]

image #2 - **with my attempt** (both attempts end up with same result):

[image]

AAAAAAAAAAAH, I'm clueless!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [whitespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace) is largely ignored, outputting a newline (`\n`) won't actually insert a line break. Instead, just use the [line break tag (`<br>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br).

In JSX, that looks like `<br />`. Since you need to return a single element, you'll also want wrap your text and line break in a [fragment (`<>...</>`)](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
<text>
    About:{" "}
    {this.props.fact.map((f) => (
        <>
            {f}
            <br />
        </>
    ))}
</text>
```

Comment: Or you could `flatMap` into `[f, <br />]` if you're fancy :3

Comment: @caTS me likey likey. p.s, answer worked like a charm. thanks!

Comment: Typically you don't want the trailing `<br />`, though.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just text, you could use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.fact.join('\n') }} />
```